# Join SUM value of "not-equal-to" lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, left-join

I have two tables which I need to join as I illustrate below:

[image]

Simply, I need to find the SUM value of the lines from Table2 where POLE values are not equal the value in Table1. What kind of query would work?

You can download the spreadsheet [from this link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6YM4zGViqldWWtJMEtTUm01bkhZQTF4X3IzZkR4X2YzYmJn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the desired result?   You know you can join on `t1.Pole<>t2.Pole` right?   Is that all you need to know?

Comment: Don't provide your data as an image; it isn't useful to other users as we can't interact with it. [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Could you explain little bit more...?

Comment: (just telling him about proper question in his own language) - Soru sorarken resim yerine duz yazi seklinde verirsen herkesin senin elindeki verinin bir ornegiyle kod yazıp test etme şansı olur. Genel olarak ne istediğini çok güzel göstermişsin.

Comment: Thank you for all feedbacks! I have edited the post by adding the spreadsheet. I show what I need with sumifs formula. Dear  @TabAlleman, `t1.Pole<>t2.Pole` creates duplicates, I need a single line with SUM. Dear Cetin, I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from table1 t
    cross apply (
        select sum(t2.oh) as oh_oth, sum(t2."max") as max_oth
        from table2 t2
        where t2.pole <> t.pole
    ) oth
```

Comment: This is much better with a slight correction to last where clause: t1.Pole <> t.Pole

Comment: Thx. Scrolling back and forth to get the right names.

Comment: I know I know :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.Pole, t1.Org, t1.Item, t1.OH, t1.[MAX],
(select sum(OH) from table2 t2 where t2.Pole <> t1.Pole) as [OH in other poles],
(select sum([MAX]) from table2 t2 where t2.Pole <> t1.Pole) as [MAX in other poles]
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cetin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046903/2527905) returns your expected answer set, but it might be more efficient to combine both Scalar Subqueries into one:

```
WITH cte AS 
 ( -- calculate both MAX & SUM using a Cross Join
   SELECT t1.pole
      ,Sum(t2.oh) AS otherSum
      ,Max(t2.[Max]) AS otherMax
   FROM table2 AS t2 CROSS JOIN table2 AS t1
   WHERE t2.Pole <> t1.Pole
   GROUP BY t1.pole
 )
SELECT t1.*, cte.otherSum, cte.otherMax
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN cte -- can be an Inner Join if all POLEs exist in both tables 
  ON t1.pole = cte.pole
```